# Can I configure Accessbility settings using Terminal instead of Preferences Panel

Tags: system-settings, accessibility

I have a problem with my MacBookPro, the left click button on (any) mouse doesnt work and the trackpad doesnt respond to any clicks, so the only thing that works properly is the keyboard and Mouse Right Click/Middle Click.

I was looking at the Accessibility preferences and can see there is something call Enable Mouse Keys, does this option allow you to effect a left-mouse click with a keyboard combination, I also Speakable Items. Both would make my life easier until computer fixed, but unfortunately without a working mouse there seems to be no way of selecting these items.

Is there a way I can set these values from the commandline, because mouse right-click and middle-click work I can open a Terminal Window and enter commands from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.universalaccess mouseDriver 1
```

Also you can always access **Spotlight** by typing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (unless you've changed the default keyboard shortcut for that).  From there if you type `trackpad` you should be able to get to your trackpad preferences.

Comment: Thankyou that did work, but then I found I couln't type anything in, apparently a side effect of using mouse keys without having a numeric keyboard. However I then found that pressing Option key 5 times toggles between Mouse Keys On/Off so I can just toggle on whenever I need to do a mouse click, thanks. I also enabled Speakable items but canot get that working, Ive also checked my trackpad settings but there is nothing wrong with my settings my trackpad just fails to work.